# Does the TFS lock icon only appear for solutions added to source control?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, version-control

We have a solution in TFS with 37 projects. Recently we added a business class library, but it appears in solution explorer with the C# symbol in a square. However when I click the arrow to display the files in the project nothing appears with a lock symbol.

If I right click the project, I get an option to add solution to source control with a folder and check mark icon. Is this necessary in order to get the lock icon showing?

I know it's source controlled b/c if I go to Team Explorer --> Source Control Explorer, the project is there and I can get the latest. However because there is no lock symbol, it seems I must do all check ins through source control explorer, I can't do it from Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. you must do all check ins through source control explorer, not with Solution Explorer.

It seems that the Project file does not have the correct binding to TFS. Try to unbind/bind in VS, just go to **File > Source Control > Advanced... > Change Source Control...** Select the specific project (it'll probably look fine and valid), click **Unbind**, ok the warning then click **Bind** (the same toolbar button relabelled) Ok that window, and checkout all the files it suggests. This will make the necessary changes and the padlocks should appear. Review and check the changes to keep them.

More detail info please refer this question in SO: [Project not showing as checked-in to TFS in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186220/project-not-showing-as-checked-in-to-tfs-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: TYSM! I would also like to add that after I did this, I also included the check in of the main solution file, which when compared, showed the extra project I was trying to add.