# Visual Studio 2015 TFS Check In Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

When I am attempting to check in code in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 to TFS, I get the following message:

[image]

When this happens I have to close the solution to be able to Check In my work, which is very inconvenient. Does anyone know what I need to do to correct this? This was working correctly before I installed Update 3 to Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Did this just occur with a  specific solution？

Comment: It is occurring with all solutions. I am attempting to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio this morning to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Should be. Have tested with my VS updated 3. Everything works well.

Comment: Others in my organization are not having any issues. I was able to reinstall, but with the same issues. I found another question on Stack Overflow that was similar and they said they were able to fix it with a repair, but not a re-install, so I am attempting that now.

Answer (score 0):

If this can work with other solutions. Suggest you to **unbind/bind** the solution and try to check in it again. (undo pengding changes first) Detail ways please refer: [Project not showing as checked-in to TFS in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186220/project-not-showing-as-checked-in-to-tfs-in-visual-studio-2013)

Also [clear VS and TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) before the check in.

Answer (score 0):

New Machine fixed it. Must have been an issue with the hard disk.