# Pending Changes dialog shows files outside solution that shouldn't be there

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

If I open VS without opening a project/solution, I get a list of files in Pending Changes.  The folders marked in red are solutions in my workspace, and those marked in green are branches of the solution.

However, when I open the respective solutions directly, none of those files are there.  Somehow there is some overlap of what VS/TFS thinks needs to be checked in, even though in this case it is wrong.

I opened each solution from Pending Changes in turn, and there are no files to be checked in.  I don't understand what (or why) it's showing me this list, and am concerned that if I accidentally check-in while showing "All" pending changes instead of solution-specific ones, that I will lose work.

Can anyone please explain why its showing these "phantom" pending check-ins?  Even more bizarelly, the same of the solution in the title bar of pending changes is not even remotely related to some of the files shown.

If I delete my workspace, then create a fresh one, and then get recent, the problem goes away for a few weeks, but then randomly files start to appear back here.

[image]

Comment: Look at your workspaces. Do you have different sets of workspaces for different paths? Are some local vs server workspaces?

Comment: Hi. I deleted the old workspace on my machine, leaving just this one.  Sadly the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a source control binding error or some TFS cache issue.

Try to **unbind/ bind** this files in source control. *File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control*

*File > Source Control > Add to Source Control*

Detail ways please refer: [Project not showing as checked-in to TFS in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186220/project-not-showing-as-checked-in-to-tfs-in-visual-studio-2013)

Also give a try with [clear VS and TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion.  In the meantime I was able to fix this by using the latest branch as the base/main branch, deleting all former parent branches; using this branch as the point from which to move forwards.  Bizarelly, it also removed the files that were flagged as pending that existed outside the (and unrelated to any) solution.  I'm going to monitor this closely and flag to MS as an issue when it happens again.  Thank you.